# How to access just one row without storing in memory the entire table?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Using SQLite Version 3.

[image]

I am calling the `ExecuteScalar` method on this command:
`command.CommandText = "SELECT Val FROM TableName WHERE Id = 2";`

**The problem is that when I use memory reading software to access the memory space of my application, I can find all 3 strings stored in this table in the `Val` column.**

Given the `Id` column that is a Primary Key, how can I get the 2nd `Val` cell (`a60fd4d5-83d0-4665-9250-329ec6d498d4`) without accessing and storing in memory the other two `Val` cells?

What would be the correct SQL command to access just one row without accessing the rest of the rows in the table?

*NOTE: I am not asking how to access a single record/row from a table. I know how to do that, I am asking how to access it without storing the entire table in the memory space of the application. Assuming I would have 10 million rows and I want to access just one, I don't want all 10 million stored in the memory.*

Comment: Your SQL command is not the problem. Have you checked how your table is indexed?

Comment: How can I check that? Or how can I even control that when I create the database?

Comment: https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: @KobyDouek the primary key is set to auto-increment and the sort order is ASC

Comment: auto-increment has nothing to do with indexing...

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table in total?

Comment: Just 3 for the example, but my question is if there's a way to access one of them without storing the other 2 in memory. @KobyDouek told me to check how my table is indexed and I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: You need to add much more data, maybe around 10MB worth of data into that table before you can justify a statement like saying it's holding the entire table in memory.

Comment: @AshleyPillay yes, you're right, it indeed doesn't hold the entire table in memory, just the accessed pages of the table. That still isn't a solution to my problem as I am concerned about security more than performance. But there might not be a solution given the way databases work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database files are organized into pages, which have a size of 4 KB by default.
It does not make sense to attempt to read smaller portions from disk (because that is the default block size that file systems use nowadays), and in many cases [increasing the page size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size) would increase performance.

If you want to check that the database does not access more rows than needed, look at the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).
If you really want to use that memory reading software, ensure that your table is larger than one page; make it at least some megabytes to be sure.
(For less than a few megabytes, any kind of optimization would be pointless.)

Comment: My concern is not about performance but it's related more to security. I don't want a user to be able to find in memory strings that I am not explicitly accessing.

After populating several pages, indeed, the data from other pages doesn't get stored in memory, so that's a good thing for performance, it still doesn't solve my problem though. But I am guessing there's no solution to what I want.

Comment: When a user can access the memory used by SQLite, he is also likely to be able to read the database file directly. If you have security concers, you must encrypt everything.

Comment: Yes, everything is encrypted, I just want to prevent the user from being able to pull from memory strings that are on the same page with the record I'm selecting.

Comment: You have to encrypt rows, not the database file.

Comment: I understand, that makes sense and I kind of had the hunch that's what I'd have to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Provided `Id` is the key of the table and it's the clustered index or a unique non-clustered index, you are using the right syntax.

There's no point trying to profile SQL Server unless you have a serious performance issue.

This is premature optimization.

SQL Server is heavily optimized for performance, the team that wrote it know what their doing.

If I had to hazard a guess about what you're seeing, I would say SQL Server has followed the index b-tree & has arrived at a leaf page. It is then reading the entire page into memory. At 8KB, this is not a lot of data. This value of 8KB per page was carefully chosen to balance performance with other considerations like storage cost.
It is then returning the data in the required slots on that page.

In your case, that is just 1 slot from the page.

Since your sample data is small & sequential all the rows would likely be on the same page.

Comment: Ashley, the OP is not using SQL Server. He is using SQLite.

Comment: My mistake, I usually browse SQL Server & C# tags. Someone else may have a better answer, but I'm guessing most RDBMS have similar internals like a b-tree for index management, and read the entire leaf node in one shot.